# Youtube Data API v3 using Google service account java

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, jwt

i am integrating video upload feature in my website using #google Service Account and I am using Youtube Data api v3 java library.

When i run the below code it is giving me run time exception. Please help me .. Thanks in Advance..

Here is my java code ..

```
package com.a2z.integration.youtube;


import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;

import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube.Activities;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
/**
 *
 * @author sunil
 */
public class ServiceAuthToken
{
   final static HttpTransport TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
    static JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

   public static void main(String []g) throws Exception
   {
      List<String>scops = new <String>ArrayList();
      scops.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube");

      GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
      .setTransport(TRANSPORT)
      .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
      .setServiceAccountId(Constants.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID)
      .setServiceAccountScopes(scops)
      .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("key.p12"))
      //.setClientSecrets("*******.apps.googleusercontent.com","")
      .setClientSecrets(GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY,new InputStreamReader(java.io.Reader.class.getResourceAsStream("client_secrets.json"))))
      .build();

      YouTube youtube =  new YouTube.Builder(TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY,credential).setApplicationName("gleaming-scene-655").build();

      Activities act = youtube.activities();
      Activities.List list = act.list("s");
   }
}
```

Exception which i am getting in Console :

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory.configure(Lorg/codehaus/jackson/JsonGenerator$Feature;Z)Lorg/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory;
    at com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory.<init>(JacksonFactory.java:48)
    at com.a2z.integration.youtube.ServiceAuthToken.<clinit>(ServiceAuthToken.java:28)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get valid Credential for Google service account?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077431/how-can-i-get-valid-credential-for-google-service-account)

Comment: Yes bro i have posted it two time.. :P