# How can I get valid Credential for Google service account?

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, jwt

Hi I am developing a web application where end user will be able to upload video, and that video I want to upload in YouTube server using YouTube data API-V3. So that I am using **YouTube data API V3** **java library** But I am unable to run the code, it gives me runtime Exception . Please help me . I am waiting for your valuable responses ..

Here is my code

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;

import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube.Activities;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ServiceAuthToken
{
   final static HttpTransport TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
    static JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

   public static void main(String []g) throws Exception
   {
      List<String>scops = new <String>ArrayList();
      scops.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube");

      GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
      .setTransport(TRANSPORT)
      .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
      .setServiceAccountId(Constants.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID)
      .setServiceAccountScopes(scops)
      .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("key.p12"))
      //.setClientSecrets("*******.apps.googleusercontent.com","")
      .setClientSecrets(GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY,new InputStreamReader(java.io.Reader.class.getResourceAsStream("client_secrets.json"))))
      .build();

      YouTube youtube =  new YouTube.Builder(TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY,credential).setApplicationName("gleaming-scene-655").build();

      Activities act = youtube.activities();
      Activities.List list = act.list("s");
   }
}
```

Exception :

```
    run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory.configure(Lorg/codehaus/jackson/JsonGenerator$Feature;Z)Lorg/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory;
    at com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory.<init>(JacksonFactory.java:48)
    at com.a2z.integration.youtube.ServiceAuthToken.<clinit>(ServiceAuthToken.java:28)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: The YouTube API does not work with service accounts. You can only use oAuth2 authentication so that a user will upload a video into his/her own account.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Well if the error is from Jackson, regarding this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784051/nosuchmethoderror-org-codehaus-jackson-type-javatype) ou can correct the error first and see what happend next.

After the authentification you can use the official code to upload videos with API YouTube V3 using Java

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2012 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except
 * in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License
 * is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express
 * or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
 * the License.
 */

package com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.data;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener;
import com.google.api.client.http.InputStreamContent;
import com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.Auth;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.Video;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.VideoSnippet;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.VideoStatus;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Upload a video to the authenticated user's channel. Use OAuth 2.0 to
 * authorize the request. Note that you must add your video files to the
 * project folder to upload them with this application.
 *
 * @author Jeremy Walker
 */
public class UploadVideo {

    /**
     * Define a global instance of a Youtube object, which will be used
     * to make YouTube Data API requests.
     */
    private static YouTube youtube;

    /**
     * Define a global variable that specifies the MIME type of the video
     * being uploaded.
     */
    private static final String VIDEO_FILE_FORMAT = "video/*";

    private static final String SAMPLE_VIDEO_FILENAME = "sample-video.mp4";

    /**
     * Upload the user-selected video to the user's YouTube channel. The code
     * looks for the video in the application's project folder and uses OAuth
     * 2.0 to authorize the API request.
     *
     * @param args command line args (not used).
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files
        // to the authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow
        // other types of access.
        List<String> scopes = Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload");

        try {
            // Authorize the request.
            Credential credential = Auth.authorize(scopes, "uploadvideo");

            // This object is used to make YouTube Data API requests.
            youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(
                    "youtube-cmdline-uploadvideo-sample").build();

            System.out.println("Uploading: " + SAMPLE_VIDEO_FILENAME);

            // Add extra information to the video before uploading.
            Video videoObjectDefiningMetadata = new Video();

            // Set the video to be publicly visible. This is the default
            // setting. Other supporting settings are "unlisted" and "private."
            VideoStatus status = new VideoStatus();
            status.setPrivacyStatus("public");
            videoObjectDefiningMetadata.setStatus(status);

            // Most of the video's metadata is set on the VideoSnippet object.
            VideoSnippet snippet = new VideoSnippet();

            // This code uses a Calendar instance to create a unique name and
            // description for test purposes so that you can easily upload
            // multiple files. You should remove this code from your project
            // and use your own standard names instead.
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            snippet.setTitle("Test Upload via Java on " + cal.getTime());
            snippet.setDescription(
                    "Video uploaded via YouTube Data API V3 using the Java library " + "on " + cal.getTime());

            // Set the keyword tags that you want to associate with the video.
            List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
            tags.add("test");
            tags.add("example");
            tags.add("java");
            tags.add("YouTube Data API V3");
            tags.add("erase me");
            snippet.setTags(tags);

            // Add the completed snippet object to the video resource.
            videoObjectDefiningMetadata.setSnippet(snippet);

            InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent(VIDEO_FILE_FORMAT,
                    UploadVideo.class.getResourceAsStream("/sample-video.mp4"));

            // Insert the video. The command sends three arguments. The first
            // specifies which information the API request is setting and which
            // information the API response should return. The second argument
            // is the video resource that contains metadata about the new video.
            // The third argument is the actual video content.
            YouTube.Videos.Insert videoInsert = youtube.videos()
                    .insert("snippet,statistics,status", videoObjectDefiningMetadata, mediaContent);

            // Set the upload type and add an event listener.
            MediaHttpUploader uploader = videoInsert.getMediaHttpUploader();

            // Indicate whether direct media upload is enabled. A value of
            // "True" indicates that direct media upload is enabled and that
            // the entire media content will be uploaded in a single request.
            // A value of "False," which is the default, indicates that the
            // request will use the resumable media upload protocol, which
            // supports the ability to resume an upload operation after a
            // network interruption or other transmission failure, saving
            // time and bandwidth in the event of network failures.
            uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(false);

            MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener progressListener = new MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener() {
                public void progressChanged(MediaHttpUploader uploader) throws IOException {
                    switch (uploader.getUploadState()) {
                        case INITIATION_STARTED:
                            System.out.println("Initiation Started");
                            break;
                        case INITIATION_COMPLETE:
                            System.out.println("Initiation Completed");
                            break;
                        case MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS:
                            System.out.println("Upload in progress");
                            System.out.println("Upload percentage: " + uploader.getProgress());
                            break;
                        case MEDIA_COMPLETE:
                            System.out.println("Upload Completed!");
                            break;
                        case NOT_STARTED:
                            System.out.println("Upload Not Started!");
                            break;
                    }
                }
            };
            uploader.setProgressListener(progressListener);

            // Call the API and upload the video.
            Video returnedVideo = videoInsert.execute();

            // Print data about the newly inserted video from the API response.
            System.out.println("\n================== Returned Video ==================\n");
            System.out.println("  - Id: " + returnedVideo.getId());
            System.out.println("  - Title: " + returnedVideo.getSnippet().getTitle());
            System.out.println("  - Tags: " + returnedVideo.getSnippet().getTags());
            System.out.println("  - Privacy Status: " + returnedVideo.getStatus().getPrivacyStatus());
            System.out.println("  - Video Count: " + returnedVideo.getStatistics().getViewCount());

        } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
            System.err.println("GoogleJsonResponseException code: " + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : "
                    + e.getDetails().getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            System.err.println("Throwable: " + t.getMessage());
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert?hl=fr

Comment: Thanks @Martialp for your reply .. The concern is I want to Authorize my application using service account. You forward me the link which is for end user authorization. Please help me , I am got stuck.

Comment: When this line executes -- static JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

it gives error i.e.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory
at com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.<init>(JacksonFactory.java:45)

Comment: Sorry I was little busy.. now I have got auth token successfully ..

thanks @Martialp